# A custom sub-domain via AWS CloudFront fails over https on S3 website, but works fine over HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt, wildcard-subdomain

I created a Let's Encrypt wildcard certificate for `*.example.cz` on Amazon Linux EC2 instance using CertBot.
The certificate attached to nginx web server on EC2, website works fine both over HTTP and HTTPS. There are couple of DNS records `www.example.cz` and `*.example.cz` of type `A` with EC2 IP Address.

Then to point a subdomain `cdn.example.cz` to a S3 Static Website Bucket:

1. I imported the same wildcard SSL certificate from EC2 to AWS Certificate Manager.
2. Created a CloudFront distribution with the imported SSL Certificate.
3. Created a CNAME record `cdn.example.cz` and pointed it to S3 bucket's URL.

When I request an object from S3 using `http://cdn.example.cz/object.jpg` it works, but the request over HTTPS keeps busy until reaches time out.

I tried CloudFront's Alternate domain names to be `cdn.example.cz`, and also tried `www.example.cz` `example.cz`. None worked.

**AWS Certificate Manager**
[image: AWS Certificate Manager]

**CloudFront Distribution**
[image: CloudFront Distribution]

**CloudFront Distribution Origins**
[image: CloudFront Distribution Origins]

Comment: What is your origin setup? match viewer?

Comment: tried both `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS` and `HTTP and HTTPS`, screenshots uploaded

Answer (score 0):

`CNAME` record had to be pointed to CloudFront Distribution domain name
`xxxxxxx..cloudfront.net`

I'm not sure about this but I also removed `eu-south-1` from Origin domain name so it's now `cdn.example.cz.s3.amazonaws.com`

Once I updated CloudFront distribution, I had to wait few hours for the change propagated properly (as it was initially pointing to S3 before I was aware that CloudFront was required for SSL). As soon as it was, this settings worked perfectly.